# C# Copy Mutiple Cells from Excel to Word in same column

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to fill Word document with Excel data, but I can fill only the first cell in each column. How can I fill in a multiple columns?

```
I want to change "missing" into "credits" somehow but I really don't know how to correctly do it: 

app.Selection.Find.Execute ("credits", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, tmp [0], 2);


private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;
object filename = "D:\\Exceltowordtemp\\report1.docx";
object missing = Type.Missing;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
doc = app.Documents.Open(filename, missing, missing);
app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

string[] tmp = new string[4];
tmp = readExcel(i);

app.Selection.Find.Execute("<credits>", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, tmp[0],2);
app.Selection.Find.Execute("<marks>", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, tmp[1],2);
app.Selection.Find.Execute("<ng>", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, tmp[2],2);
app.Selection.Find.Execute("<eg>", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, tmp[3],2);

object SaveAsFile = (object)"D:\\Exceltowordtemp\\outcomes" + tmp[0] + ".doc";
doc.SaveAs2(SaveAsFile, missing, missing, missing);
}
```

I want multiple cells in the same column to output in one Word Document. Right now it's only one per column

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for your purposes, Word wasn't designed to work this way. It's not possible to write an array to a Word table in one step - neither in rows nor in columns.

What Word can do is convert character-delimited text to a table, but that's the extent of it.

That means the code will need to loop the `tmp[]` array to fill each cell in the column.